# Function to get row data works only in responsive mode in Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables

When I click on the image in Reponsive mode, it will return the row data in console. But in normal view I get Undefined error.

```
         var table =  $('.dataTable').DataTable({
                "responsive": true,                                   
                "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": 4,
                    "data": null,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        if (type === 'display') {
                            data = "<a href='#' width='30px' class='editMe' data='" + full[0] + "'><img src='/images/edit.png' width='30px' /></a>";
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                } ,

                {
                       "targets": 0,
                       "visible": false,
                       "searchable": false
                }]
           });


           $('.dataTable').on('click', '.editMe', function () {

               console.log(table.row(this).data());

           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below instead:

```js
$('.dataTable').on('click', '.editMe', function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    if($row.hasClass('child')){ $row = $row.prev(); }
    console.log(table.row($row).data());
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/8uahpyL1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: In this case does not work in responsive mode. I use console.log(table.row($(this).parents('tr'))); and in worked in both mode. thank you for answer

Comment: @Amin, you're right, I have corrected the answer and added example demonstrating that it works in both modes.